# How to get both observable and the json object of an item using angularfire2

Tags: typescript, angularfire2, ionic3

In the code sample below I am trying to get both an observable object and the json object of an item. I kept getting an error that the `val` is not a function of snapshot. I need a better solution.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  itemVal:any;
  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController,
              public db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.item = db.object('/testObj');
    this.item.subscribe(snapshot => {
      this.itemVal = snapshot.val(); //<-- I need the json value here -- but getting error
    });
  }
}
```